# Initialize array data from array prop in a Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vue component I have an array (of objects) prop called `selectedSuppliers`. I want to initialize a data prop called `suppliers` to `selectedSuppliers`, but any subsequent changes to `suppliers` should **not** propogate to `selectedSuppliers`.

I tried the following

```
props: {
  selectedSuppliers: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  },
},
data () {
  return {
    selected: [...this.selectedSuppliers],
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. What is the correct way to initialize an array data property to an array prop?

Answer (score 0):

If `selectedSuppliers` is an array of object, then the spread operator only performs a shallow copy of this array. It means that updating any object of `suppliers` **will** update the content of `selectedSuppliers`.

You can take a look at [this short post](https://medium.com/@justintulk/javascript-object-cloning-shallow-copies-in-x-d11bd1d9c3f1).

Comment: that's fine, I just need to clone the array

Comment: That's my point, you're not actually cloning the array using the spread operator. You just create a new array with the same objects (same reference).

Comment: yes, that's what I want: different array, same objects

Comment: Alright, so I don't get your problem. What do you mean by "it does not work"? Some errors in the console?

Comment: No errors, but the data prop is set to an empty array when the component prop is an array with one element

Answer (score 0):

This might work,

```
props: {
  selectedSuppliers: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  },
},
data () {
  return {
    selected: this.selectedSuppliers.map(o => Object.assign({}, o)
  }
}
```